# What do you call a 3-hedron?

Tags: geometry

I was just reading about polyhedrons and wondered, even though it's an impossible shape, what a 3-hedron is called?  I'm really asking what the Greek for '3'.  Does it just converge to a triangle?

Comment: ["tri"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tri) seems like the right prefix, coming from Latin and Greek.

Comment: That was my first thought, though thought 'tri' was only Latin.

Comment: A relevant reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix

Comment: how about three-hedron? lol

Comment: I call him Harvey

Comment: Do you mean a [tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron)?

Comment: @J.D.: No, tetrahedrons have 4 faces, not 3.  The question is at face value asking about an object that doesn't exist, but is really asking about a prefix meaning $3$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, it does exist, for appropriate values of «exist». An orthant deserves to be called a trihedron!

Comment: In the right ambient space, a trihedron makes sense and can exist. It's just as in spherical geometry (on the two-sphere), where you can start a figure with an angle at the north pole by drawing two longitude lines southward that will meet again at the south pole at the same angle. So in $S^3$, you can draw a trihedral angle at one pole, and continue the three “planes” to the opposite pole, where they will meet again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tri- is the greek prefix.

We do use the word trihedron, but to refer to something slightly different: the Frenet-Serret trihedron.